# How to implement role based authentication in ASP.net MVC .core 3.1 without Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I am currently working on a video streaming project which consists of 3 roles. "Admin", "Employee" and "Customers". The Administrator has the power to give an account a specific role. I cannot use Entity Framework for this. Does anyone have a good tutorial/documentation for me? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a custom attribute like this

```
// Custom [Authorized] attribute for JWT and Enum based roles
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class AuthorizedAttribute : Attribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    private readonly Roles[] _roles;
    public AuthorizedAttribute(params Roles[] roles)
    {
        _roles = roles;
    }

    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        // We're checking here to see if the route has been decorated with an [AllowAnonymous] attribute. If it has, we skip authorization
        // for the route. Doing this allows us to apply the [Authorize] attribute by default in the startup using:
        //
        // services.AddControllers().AddMvcOptions(x => x.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute()))
        //

        if (context.ActionDescriptor is ControllerActionDescriptor controllerActionDescriptor)
        {
            var hasAllowAnonymousAttribute = controllerActionDescriptor.MethodInfo.GetCustomAttributes(inherit: true)
                .Any(a => a.GetType() == typeof(AllowAnonymousAttribute));
            if (hasAllowAnonymousAttribute)
            {
                return;
            }
        }

        // Check if valid user
        var user = (AuthUser)context.HttpContext.Items["User"];
        if (user == null)
        {
            // Not logged in 
            context.Result = new ObjectResult(Logger.Error("Unauthorized request", HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized))
            { 
                StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized 
            };
            return;
        }

        // Check if valid role            
        Enum.TryParse(user.role, out Roles role);
        if (_roles.Length > 0 && !_roles.Contains(role))
        {
            // User is logged in, but the role is not allowed to access this method
            context.Result = new ObjectResult(Logger.Error($"Your current role `{user.role}` does not have access to this API", HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized))
            {
                StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized
            };
            return;
        }
    }

    
}
```

And use in your action method of Controller like this:-

```
 [HttpPost]
 [Authorized(Roles.Employee, Roles.Admin, Roles.Customers)]
 public async Task<IActionResult> Create()
 {
  //.............your code
 }
```

here is the complete example, you can refer to it and modify your implementation accordingly. No need of entity framework

Answer (score 0):

You could configure your application to log in with JWT (json web token) and set custom authentication. After user login successfully, you could generate a JWT token with Role claims, then the JWToken is used for HTTP requests, after that implement the role based authentication. More detail information, refer the following links:

[Login And Role Based Custom Authentication In ASP.NET Core 3.1](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/login-and-role-based-custom-authentication-in-asp-net-core-3-1/)

[ASP.NET Core 3.1 - Role Based Authorization Tutorial with Example API](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2019/10/16/aspnet-core-3-role-based-authorization-tutorial-with-example-api)